# Хочу изменить вручную пакет в node_modules, изменяю и ничего не происходит

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, react-router-dom

Для тестирования работы приложения хочу изменить пакет react-router-dom (в частности функцию NavLink). Зашел в node_modules/react_router_dom/ В файле index.js указан экспорт module.exports = require("./cjs/react-router-dom.js");

Зашел в файл ./cjs/react-router-dom.js и изменил функцию NavLink. После перезапуска npm run start ни чего не изменилось. Вообще если удалить все из папки react-router-dom не происходит ошибки хотя в проекте явно указано например import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

Я понимаю что изменять файлы в готовых компонентах плохая идея. Но мне это нужно для тестирования и после того как закончу - верну все обратно. Как и где можно модифицировать файл в node_modules, в частности react-router-dom чтобы изменения появлялись в проекте?

Comment: Надо зайти сюда https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/index.js нажать на карандашик, внести изменения и отправить pull request, потом ждать

Comment: Мне нужно всего лишь временно изменить пакет. И эти изменения не стоит отправлять в пулреквест

Comment: возможно используется глобально установленный модуль?

Comment: Проверил - нет. Только локальные